# Check if a string within an array appears in another string array in LINQ?

Tags: linq

This should be pretty simple but LINQ's Contains() doesn't take an array.
I have 2 arrays of strings

e.g.1 {"The","quick","Brown"}

And I want to compare another array of strings and return true if any string appears in it.

e.g.2 {"This","doesnt","quick","Work"}

So "quick" appears in the 2nd array.

Is it best making the first string joined comma delimited so it looks like "The, quick , Brown" and then running contains in a loop against it?

I'm sure this can be done properly using LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var first = new[] {"the", "quick", "brown"};
var second = new[] {"This","doesnt","quick","Work"};

var found = from a in first
            from b in second
            where a == b
            select a;

if(found.Any())
    return true;
```

Comment: This is O(n*m) whereas using `Intersect` should be O(n+m). It won't matter for examples like this, but could make a big difference for larger sequences.

Comment: @Jon: Using `Intersect` is more efficient (although probably not noticeably so if the sequences are small).

Comment: @LukeH: Ok great, how would this work for case-insensitivity too?

Comment: @Jon: `Intersect` can take an `IEqualityComparer<T>` to handle that. For example, `bool exists = first.Intersect(second, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Any();` or similar. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx

Answer (score 6):

```
bool exists = first.Intersect(second).Any();
```

Or, if you want to know what the common words actually are:

```
var commonWords = first.Intersect(second);

foreach (string s in commonWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use:

```
var query = from a in first
            where b.Contains(a)
            select a;

var isThereAMatch = query.Any();
```

If the lists were very large and matches were likely to be sparse, then I might optimise this by using a lookup/hashset for b.